# Cannot set the value of a NSString from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've searched all over google, and stack overflow for a solution, but I wasn't able to find an answer that solved my problem. Sorry for the long post, as I'm trying to give as much information as I can. I'm new to iOS and Objective- c, but not programming in general due to being asked to switch over from Android by my company, so any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to assign a value to an NSString in one class from a TextField in another, but I get the error:
 `**-[ViewController name:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78712fe0**`
when I run the app in the simulator.

Relevant code:

```
//UserInfo.h  

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface UserInfo : NSObject <NSCoding>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *age;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;

    @end

//UserInfo.m  


    #import "UserInfo.h"

    static NSString *nameKey = @"userName";
    static NSString *ageKey = @"userAge";
    static NSString *addressKey = @"userAddress";
    static NSString *userInfoKey = @"userInfoKey";

    @implementation UserInfo
    @synthesize name;
    @synthesize age;
    @synthesize address;

    - (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        self = [super init];

        self.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:nameKey];
        self.age = [coder decodeObjectForKey:ageKey];
        self.address = [coder decodeObjectForKey:addressKey];

        return self;
    }

    - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        [coder encodeObject:self.name forKey:nameKey];
        [coder encodeObject:self.age forKey:ageKey];
        [coder encodeObject:self.address forKey:addressKey];
    }

    @end

//ViewController.h


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "UserInfo.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, NSCoding>


    @property (nonatomic, strong) UserInfo *userInfoObject;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ageLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *ageText;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *addressText;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *saveBtn;

    - (IBAction)saveBtnTouched:(id)sender;

    - (void) saveUserInfo;
    - (void) loadUserInfo;
    - (void) setUserInterfaceValues;
    - (IBAction)nameText:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)ageText:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)addressText:(id)sender;

    @end

//ViewController.m


    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "UserInfo.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize titleLabel;
    @synthesize nameLabel;
    @synthesize ageLabel;
    @synthesize addressLabel;
    @synthesize nameText;
    @synthesize ageText;
    @synthesize addressText;
    @synthesize saveBtn;


    static NSString *userInfoKey = @"userInfoKey";



    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self loadUserInfo];

        if(!self.userInfoObject)
        {
            self.userInfoObject = [[UserInfo alloc] init];
        }

        [self setUserInterfaceValues];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        self.saveBtn.enabled = YES;
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
    {
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {

        [self.nameText resignFirstResponder];
        [self.ageText resignFirstResponder];
        [self.addressText resignFirstResponder];

        return YES;
    }

    - (IBAction)saveBtnTouched:(id)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ was entered into the name field", self.nameText.text);
        NSLog(@"%@ was entered into the age field", self.ageText.text);
        NSLog(@"%@ was entered into the address field", self.addressText.text);



        [self textFieldShouldEndEditing:self.nameText];
        [self textFieldShouldEndEditing:self.ageText];
        [self textFieldShouldEndEditing:self.addressText];

        self.userInfoObject.name = self.nameText.text;
        self.userInfoObject.age = self.ageText.text;
        self.userInfoObject.address = self.addressText.text;



        [self saveUserInfo];

        self.saveBtn.enabled = NO;
    }

    - (void)saveUserInfo
    {
        NSData *userInfoData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.userInfoObject];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userInfoData forKey:userInfoKey];
    }

    - (void)loadUserInfo
    {
        NSData *userInfoData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:userInfoKey];
        if(userInfoData)
        {
        self.userInfoObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userInfoData];
        }
    }

    - (void) setUserInterfaceValues
    {
        self.nameText.text = self.userInfoObject.name;
        self.ageText.text = self.userInfoObject.age;
        self.addressText.text = self.userInfoObject.address;
    }

    - (IBAction)nameText:(id)sender {
    }
    - (IBAction)ageText:(id)sender {
    }
    - (IBAction)addressText:(id)sender {
    }


    @end


//AppDelegate.h  


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "UserInfo.h"

    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;


    @end  


//AppDelegate.m  


        #import "AppDelegate.h"
        #import "ViewController.h"
        #import "UserInfo.h"

        @interface AppDelegate ()

        @end

        @implementation AppDelegate


        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            return YES;
        }

    //all the other generated methods. Taken out due to space.
    @end
```

Three breakpoints are set that are supposidly the source of the problem:

From the ViewController.m, in `- (void)setUserInterfaceValues`

`self.nameText.text = self.userInfoObject.name;`
  (I assume that this applies to the other two lines below it also)

Also from the ViewController.m, in `- (void)viewDidLoad`
`[self setUserInterfaceValues];`

And finally from the AppDelegate.m, in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

`self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;`

From what I understand, and have learned from searching this issue, the app is trying to send data to something that doesn't exist, the NSString name being the culprit. Others have suggested to make sure that my .xib file is connected to the ViewController, and I have verified that it is.

As another bit of information, I'm not using a storyboard for this app, and instead am using the interface builder. I'm aware that there are advantages to storyboards, and I would like to be using them, but my company uses the interface builder and does a lot of things programmatically, so I'm learning to develop without.

[EDIT]: Issue solved thanks to Ian.

Comment: Looks like you probably set your `NSUserDefaults` to contain the wrong object at some point, then you've been loading it out incorrectly ever since you fixed the bug.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Could you please expand upon this a little more? I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: If you previously ran this code with an incorrect pointer being assigned to your stored value in `NSUserDefaults`, that object will be loaded out again when you retrieve it. Try running it without loading the data first, then see what you get. Also, you don't need to do the same data sharing mess that Android forces you to do with `Activity`s; look into using delegate and datasource protocols to replace this behaviour.

Comment: how many view controller are you using?,Are you using navigation view controller?